# Use vue data props in other data prop

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, chart.js, chartkick

I need to use vue data props into a property called chartdata that corresponds to the vue-chartkick chart data. I want to use values like "monC" instead of the values 4,2 in line-chart component.

I have tried using moustache syntax but it did't work

```
<div id="myId">
        <line-chart :data="[['Jan', 4], ['Feb', 2], ['Mar', 10], ['Apr', 5], ['May', 3]]"></line-chart>

        <p> Monday : {{ monC }} </p>
        <p> Tuesday : {{ tueC }} </p>
        <p> Wednesday : {{ wedC }} </p>
        <p> Thursday : {{ thuC }} </p>
        <p> Friday : {{ friC }} </p>
        <p> Saturday : {{ satC }} </p>
        <p> Sunday : {{ sunC }} </p>
        <!-- <ul id="navp">

        </ul> -->

    </div>
```

```
The valiue of monC should get displayed in the chart instead of 4, 2 and others.
```

Comment: Can not really help if you do not provide your vue.js code.

Comment: Here is the [link](https://github.com/iamharmangill/charts-test/blob/master/Day.html) to the file

Comment: Shot in the dark, but have you tried  `['Jan', \`${monC}\`]`